# Need to create function for assigning set choice values based on array containing a given number

Tags: javascript, qualtrics

I am completely new to JavaScript.... So please bear with me...

I am trying to use JavaScript to pre-populate answers from a multiple choice question participants are taking early in a survey. Note my variable "Legchoice" will take on the value that is piped into here. However there can be multiple values because the respondents can choose more than one answer for that question that is to be piped in. I know that my script is asking whether "LegChoice" equals a given number.... How do I change it so that "LegChoice" contains a given number. As in what if the respondent selects the answers that corresponds to values 1 & 3 so that I can set choice values 4,5,6,7,8,9. Or what if they select answers that correspond to 2 & 4? I hope this makes sense.

Thank you!

```
var LegChoice = "${q://QID23/SelectedChoicesRecode}";
var LegChoice = parseInt(LegChoice);


    if (LegChoice==1) {
    this.setChoiceValue(4,true);
    this.setChoiceValue(5,true);
    this.setChoiceValue(6,true);
    this.setChoiceValue(7,true);
}

if (LegChoice== 2) {
    this.setChoiceValue(4,true);
    this.setChoiceValue(5,true);
    this.setChoiceValue(6,true);
    this.setChoiceValue(7,true);
}

if (LegChoice==3) {
    this.setChoiceValue(6,true);
    this.setChoiceValue(8,true);
    this.setChoiceValue(9,true);
}

if (LegChoice == 4) {
    this.setChoiceValue(1,true);
    this.setChoiceValue(3,true);
}
```

Comment: I think a better way to frame it is... If the values that are piped in are an array of numbers.... How to set my variables as in if Legchoice contains 1 then this.setchoice value..... if Legchoice contains 1,2,3,4 then...

Comment: It's worth keeping in mind that Qualtrics will return multiple answers as a comma separated string. Additionally, Java and JavaScript are very different. Qualtrics doesn't use Java.

Answer (score 1):

You need to split LegChoice into separate answers then loop through them.

```
var LegChoices = "${q://QID23/SelectedChoicesRecode}";
var that = this;
LegChoices.split(",").each(function(LegChoice,index) {
    var LegChoice = parseInt(LegChoice.trim());
    if (LegChoice==1) {
        that.setChoiceValueByRecodeValue(4,true);
        that.setChoiceValueByRecodeValue(5,true);
        that.setChoiceValueByRecodeValue(6,true);
        that.setChoiceValueByRecodeValue(7,true);
    }

    //etc...

});
```

Note: If you are piping in recode values, you need to set by recode value.